# @Html.DropdownList to show Category >> Subcategory >> Subcategory as text value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, html-select, html-helper

I have a simple `Category` class to create a self referencing table.

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId{get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;
    public int? ParentId {get;set}
    public virtual Category Parent {get;set}

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children {get;set;}
}
```

And a create view generated by EF has the out-of the box area for new category name:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new {@class = "control-label"})
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name,"", new{@class="form-control"}
```

and an area that pre-populates the parent category selection

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentId, "Parent Category", new {@class = "control-label"})
@Html.DropdownList("ParentId", null, new {@class ="form-control})
```

This allows for categories with a number of nested subcategories and additional subcategories nested under other subcategories, etc... etc...

The create view allows you to create a new category and assign a parent category using an `@Html.DropdownList` that pulls the text values of all categories but lists only the actual category or subcategory name.

Is there a way to change the display values in the `@Html.DropdownList` to display the hierarchical tree instead of a the single parent value?

So instead of the `@Html.Dropdownlist` displaying "AAA Batteries" (the value of the new category's parent category)  it shows the full hierarchical value of the parent category:

```
Electronic Supplies >> Batteries >> AAA Batteries
```

This is of course is a category named "Electronic Supplies" with a subcategory of "Batteries" and a subcategory under that of "AAA Batteries".

Comment: There is nothing out of the box that will do that. I posted an a article on Code Project [MVC Custom Select Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768069/MVC-Custom-Select-Control) with the source code showing one possibility. Other options include building the options with the parent category text perpended to the  category text, or dynamically building additional dropdownlists for child elements based on selection of the parent (using jquery and ajax)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks!  The Code Project example will definitely help.  I appreciate everyone's patience and help with me as I get deeper into MVC!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a method in your model that generates this name for you. Something like:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId {get; set;}
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public string GetFullCategoryName()
    {
        string result = this.Name;

        // note: I removed the argument because it's class member.
        Category parent = this.GetParent(); // null for top level Categories

        while (parent != null)
        {
            result = parent.Name + " >> " + result;
            parent = GetParent(parent.ParentId);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public Category GetParent()
    {
        // note: I just made this up, you would use whatever EF method you have...
        return EF.GetEntity<Category>(this.ParentId);
    }
}
```

Of course you also need a GetParent method...

**Edit:**

Here's an example to use this (making the assumption that there's a model with a  CategoryId property, and a GetAllCategories method):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategoryId, Model.GetAllCategories().Select(c => new SelectListItem() { Text = c.GetFullCategoryName(), Value = c.CategoryId }))
```

**Edit 2:**
I changed the code above to show the entire class, maybe that will make more sense?

Comment: Thanks @JimG.   I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to structure the GetParent method to supply the GetFullCategoryName() method... could you help with that? I can't figure out a proper way to do so...my apologies, this is a bit more complicated than anything I've tried before...

Comment: No problem, GetParent would be some method that takes a ParentId and returns the corresponding Category from EF. However that works for you I can't say for sure without knowing a lot more about your entities and relationships, etc. This method could be in Category or a separate static method somewhere, or whatever you prefer. The way I have it is both methods GetParent and GetFullCategoryName would both be defined in your Category class, but there's always many ways to do it. (I should have put `this.GetParent(this.ParentId)` then maybe it would be clearer.)

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I appreciate the assist and helping make sense of things for me as I get deeper into a project that requires me to expand what I've learned.